# Does reinterpret_cast with uint8_t break the Strict Aliasing Rule?

Tags: c++, c++14, strict-aliasing

Is the following code legal in terms of the Strict Aliasing Rule (and in general)?

```
const int size = 1024;
uint8_t* buffer = allocateBuffer(size);
float* float_pointer = reinterpret_cast<float*>(buffer);
std::fill(float_pointer, float_pointer + size / sizeof(float), 1.5f);
```

As far as I understand, generally speaking SAR says we cannot access (either read or write) data through a pointer of a different type - unless we use a pointer of character type.

However, in the above code we use a pointer of a non-character type (`float*`) to read or write data of (probably) a character type (`uint8_t`), which I think is illegal.

Am I correct?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98702/3476954), yes it does.

Comment: Which version of C++?  C++20 has relaxed a lot of the rules around this for basic types.  Not sure if makes this legal or not, but it does probably change the answer from previously.

Comment: @NathanOliver C++ 14 :)

Comment: @eerorika Please see corrected code.

Comment: Recap of type aliasing: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, in the above code we use a pointer of a non-character type (float*) to read or write data of (probably) a character type (uint8_t), which I think is illegal.
>
> Am I correct?

Yes.

> Is the following code legal in terms of the Strict Aliasing Rule (and in general)?

No.

---

Besides pointer aliasing, another consideration is that alignment requirement of `float` is stricter than that of `uint8_t`. There is doubt whether `uint8_t* allocateBuffer(arg)` returns a pointer that satisfies the alignment of `float`.